# Date time function

Tags: date, flask, time

Hi there I am creating a **Flask** application and I want to find out the number of days left to a certain date let's say *2nd of August*. How would I do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `datetime` library to do that:

```
from datetime import date
start_date = date(2020, 6, 2)
end_date = date(2020, 6, 11)
delta = start_date - end_date
print(delta.days)
```